# Prometheus / Grafana counter monotonicity

Tags: grafana, prometheus

Is there a way to make a Prometheus counter in Grafana truly monotonic?

The counters on my server (using the Prometheus Java library) get reset whenever the server is restarted and the counter drops to zero in Grafana too. I cannot find a way in the documentation for Prometheus queries. Neither does the Java library provide a way to make a Counter persistent over restarts.

Comment: Did you find a solution on how to return a monotonically increasing value from a counter?

Comment: No, I didn't :(

Comment: I'd say gauges can be used for this use-case

Answer (score 7):

With counters, you almost never care about the value itself, but only about its rate of increase. Thus, counters are always meant to be used in combination with the `rate()` or `increase()` functions. These functions handle counter resets for you (any non-monotonic increase will be treated as a counter reset and neutralized in the rate calculation).

Comment: Well, I almost never care, except in this case I do. That's why I'm asking the question. The rate() and increase() functions do not seem to help me when I'm looking for the grand total value of the counter, with counter reset handling.

Comment: As @brian-brazil mentioned, the rate() and increase() handle counter resets and will therefore give the grand total (over the period of time defined in your range vector). If you're seeing an inconsistent value using this approach, one issue I've had is when multiple workers are running and you're not using a multiprocess collector, in which case counter resets will be falsely identified.

Comment: The issue with `rate` and `increase` is that they will only respect the counters values over a specific time. As far as I understood @raimohanska, they want to have a continuous counter from the beginning of time. Here the issues is, that prometheus stores timelines only for some time, so after 30 days (or how you configured it) it deletes the old data. Generally the increase per day or month is more helpful then the one over all times, as you can easily compare it with the value of the previous day. An absolute high number is difficult to compare with your previous days number

Answer (score 1):

The way to approach this is to use the `rate` function, which handles counter resets.

Comment: My understanding is that rate() doesn't help me to get the "grand total" with counter reset handling. Am I wrong?